# AJAX onreadystatechange function not always called

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, readystate, onreadystatechange

I have a AJAX call to retrieve some XML using the below method. Often when I run the code it does not enter the `onreadystatechange` function until the last iterations of my foreach loop. I'm assuming this is because the calls to `"www.webpage.com/" + arrayValue` are taking enough time that before the state is updated to "Ready" and then the next request beings. The method probably only runs for the last iteration of the loop because there is no other request to override it and thus has time to become "Ready". From what I've seen online you can't really do a tradition Wait() statement in javascipt or AJAX to give the calls time to complete. So how can I overcome this issue?

```
var getXML = new XMLHttpRequest();

myArray.forEach((arrayValue, index) => {
    getXML.open("GET", "www.webpage.com/" + arrayValue, true);
    getXML.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    getXML.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa(":something"));
    getXML.send(null);
    getXML.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
             Console.Log("We made it in!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to use the **same** XMLHttpRequest object for multiple requests.

Don't do that. Create a new, clean instance of XMLHttpRequest for **each** request.

```
myArray.forEach((arrayValue, index) => {
    var getXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getXML.open("GET", "www.webpage.com/" + arrayValue, true);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write.  From the Mozilla WebAPI -- "Note: Calling this method for an already active request (one for which open() has already been called) is the equivalent of calling abort()."